# Retaining property value after CABasicAnimation

Tags: objective-c, ios, cashapelayer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Objective-C - CABasicAnimation applying changes after animation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11515647/objective-c-cabasicanimation-applying-changes-after-animation)

Using the following code, I'm animating the drawing of a circle:

```
CAShapeLayer circle = [CAShapeLayer layer];
circle.strokeEnd = 0;
...
[self.view.layer addSublayer:circle];

CABasicAnimation *drawAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"strokeEnd"];
drawAnimation.beginTime = CACurrentMediaTime() + 3;
drawAnimation.duration = 1.0;
drawAnimation.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0f];
drawAnimation.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0f];
drawAnimation.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseIn];
drawAnimation.removedOnCompletion = NO;
drawAnimation.fillMode  = kCAFillModeForwards;
[circle addAnimation:drawAnimation forKey:@"drawShape"];
```

Whilst this draws fine, it seems `circle.strokeEnd` isn't actually updated to 1. How can I do this?

Comment: …and [Animating CAGradientLayer's locations property in a UIScrollView mask resets after completion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11068631/animating-cagradientlayers-locations-property-in-a-uiscrollview-mask-resets-aft)

Comment: …and [Animation of stroke of circle segment ends in complete stroke](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9142888/animation-of-stroke-of-circle-segment-ends-in-complete-stroke)